# Role management in Olingo JPA oData

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, olingo

I found an `Olingo` implementation for fetching and modifying data in a database by using OData protocol in this [repository](https://github.com/jpenninkhof/odata-boilerplate).

Now the question is, if we assume I have a mechanism for detecting the user by using `JWT` same as [here](https://github.com/isopropylcyanide/Jwt-Spring-Security-JPA), how can I implement the access management for `OData` sets as well?

On the other hand, if we could detect the user's role (e.g. Admin, Employee, ...) how can I define, who can do what? I mean who can do each of CURD actions on each set? **I am looking for the best practice approach!** For example, maybe by using annotations? I don't want to implement some stupid sets of *if then else*!

Also, I am very amateur in spring!

Comment: Why not the approach that SAP is using in [SAP CAP](https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/guides/authorization#user-specific-restrictions-with-requires-and-restri)?

Comment: I will check it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Authorization approach](https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/guides/authorization#user-specific-restrictions-with-requires-and-restri) from SAP Cloud Application Programming Model with declarations on the data model that revoke all default access and grant individual privileges.

You will find an overview of this concept in Unit 5: Authorization and Authentication in week 3 of OpenSAP training: ["Building Applications with SAP Cloud Application Programming Model"](https://open.sap.com/courses/cp7).